# How to use viewpager in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I am trying to add view pager in listview but when i am trying to change the view pager page it is affecting the Listview gesture i mean gesture of both listview and pager is working together

***But i wantthat , if i am flipping the pager of viewpgaer the listview would not be scrolled is there any solution for this***

I have added view pager in listview successfully but please solve this problem :( . am also trying to add gesture but not successful

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution from here: http://dallasgutauckis.com/2013/04/30/android-putting-a-viewpager-inside-a-listview/

> The problem with putting a ViewPager inside a ListView is that it takes only a small amount of vertical (Y) delta before the ListView begins to consume touch events instead of delegating to the child in order to enable the scrolling of the ListView. That’s fine, but the problem often occurs after the ViewPager has already started processing a page change (when dragging horizontally), producing a poor user experience resulting in the improper pagination and scrolling of the two views.
>
> There are a few ways to try to handle this.

1. You could not do it at all (thanks Dianne and Mark)
2. You can set a touch listener on the ListView and try to delegate the
   touches based on which view you think needs to get the touches and
   what actions need to occur based on those touches.
3. You can also combine a touch listener with GestureDetector to try to
   make the implementation a little less cumbersome. The problem is
   that in some ListViews, our layouts are a little more complex than
   single item rows of text. If the item layout has for instance a
   Button, we’d then need to properly delegate the touch event down to
   the Button. This obviously has huge ramifications for implementation
   and testing. In order to avoid the aforementioned shenanigans, I
   added an OnPageChangeListener to the ViewPager and based on the
   state of the pager, forced a touch delegate from the Activity.

> Contrived example:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private View mTouchTarget;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            private int mPreviousState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // NO-OP
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // NO-OP
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // All of this is to inhibit any scrollable container from consuming our touch events as the user is changing pages
                if (mPreviousState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                        mTouchTarget = mViewPager;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                        mTouchTarget = null;
                    }
                }

                mPreviousState = state;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mTouchTarget != null) {
            boolean wasProcessed = mTouchTarget.onTouchEvent(ev);

            if (!wasProcessed) {
                mTouchTarget = null;
            }

            return wasProcessed;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

> Now, we have a ViewPager that retains control of touch events once the page starts changing and releases it when paging is idle or settling.

Comment: can use this dispatchTouchEvent() method in base adapater

Comment: because my pager in base adapter

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this similar question on my other post.

It's working perfect for me and it looks great. 
Try this link and this may help you and others:

[View Pager in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview/24113158#24113158)

Hope this link help other viewers..:)