# How can i work with viewpager as listview row items in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, android-viewpager

I want to load images from server to viewpager as row in listview. Main problem is all viewpager have added same images. I want to add different different iamges into different viewpager.
I have visited this link but iam not getting to much that i want. Link is [View Pager in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview/26440265#26440265)