# Implementing swipeable item inside a listview for android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am making an app for android.In my app I will have a listview.Each listview row item will have to be swipeable.The row property will be kind of like viewpager. swipe and move one item. The row property is simillar like the facebook android app advertisement.Where a group of add is shown.In first look it will be look like that a viewpager is used as a listview row child. The problem is if I use a viewpager as a row nothing is view the entire row is empty.

Is there any tutorial or anything that will help me to do that.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview

Comment: The problem was for me was with the height.It was giving 0.that is why it wasn't visible.I did it as same as the link.

Comment: The answer was given before.Answer link is given here->[solution][1]


  [1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview