# How to show ViewPager inside a row of ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am trying to build an app that requires a ViewPager to be shown in ListView. Which is similar to FlipKart or SnapDeal apps.

Although I am not sure that this is what they have done so I am just guessing that this might have been implemented. So, if there is a better solution then I am certainly open to it.

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview) and [this link](http://android-java-development.blogspot.in/2012/05/system.html) and what I have done so far follows:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<MyPagerAdaper> adapers=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            ArrayList<String> list=getNewList();
            MyPagerAdaper pagerAdaper=new MyPagerAdaper(list);
            adapers.add(pagerAdaper);
        }
        MyListAdapter listAdapter=new MyListAdapter(adapers);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getNewList() {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Pankaj");
        list.add("Manisha");
        list.add("Pari");
        list.add("Piggy");
        list.add("Harish");
        return list;
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private ArrayList<MyPagerAdaper> adapers;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<MyPagerAdaper> adapers) {
            this.adapers = adapers;
            inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return adapers.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return adapers.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view=convertView;
            Viewholder viewholder;
            if(view==null){
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
                viewholder=new Viewholder();
                viewholder.pager= (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
                view.setTag(viewholder);
            }else {
                viewholder= (Viewholder) view.getTag();
            }
            MyPagerAdaper adaper= (MyPagerAdaper) getItem(position);
            viewholder.pager.setAdapter(adaper);
            return view;
        }
        private class Viewholder{
            ViewPager pager;
        }
    }

    private class MyPagerAdaper extends PagerAdapter{
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyPagerAdaper(ArrayList<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
            inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_page, container, false);
            TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            String s=list.get(position);
            textView.setText(s);
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that nothing shows up on screen except a thin grey bar at the top under the action bar.

**Edit1:**
Sorry I had missed the getCount() method. I have made the corrections but the problem remains.

**Edit2:**
I have updated the code above after the changes.

**Edit3:**
This is how the screen looks like.
[image]
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: still the getcount methoe returns 0 in MyPagerAdaper.

Comment: you can try now. i have updated the code above.

Comment: still not working after adding the view in container?

Comment: No. The items are getting added to the adapters, but they are not getting displayed.

Comment: avoid the  viewHolder class and try adding a view pager xml within your layout_list_item file. and access it with its id within the getView() method of your MyListAdapter, and set adapter to that viewpager. Insted of creting a new view variable use convertView to get the layout_list_item file.  Just a try, and please tell me it works or not. I cant see any other mistake in your code.

Comment: Actually I added viewholder after the code did not work. But I am not sure I understand 'adding a view pager xml within your layout_list_item file'. Can you please explain that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92719/discussion-between-hari-krishnan-and-opax-web).

Answer (score 0):

Inside MyPagerAdaper,Change this method

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

to

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

and Inside instantiateItem methode add view to the container like this :

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
.
.  
.
container.addView(view);
return view;
}
```