# Open a Viewpager on click of a row in RecyclerView

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am loading items into a Recyclerview from SQL Db. The recyclerview displays only the titles fetched from the database. These titles have corresponding text under the "story" column in the DB. I am trying to achieve it such that when a user clicks a row (eg. Row 0) on the recyclerview, it opens a ViewPager activity that loads a fragment that will load the corresponding "stories" stored in the DB for the row that was clicked and then being able to swipe horizontally to the next row (row 1), and show the corresponding story.

I do not know how I can be able to load the titles to the viewpager from its PagerAdapter when swiped, as well as getting the corresponding stories stored in the DB to show accordingly.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapterQuest extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<RememberItems> rememberItemsList;
private RememberAdapter remAdapter;
VerDbHandler verDbHandler;
private Context context;


public TabsPagerAdapterQuest(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context c, List<RememberItems> rememberItemsList) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    context = c;
    this.rememberItemsList = rememberItemsList;
    this.verDbHandler = new VerDbHandler(context);
}

// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    rememberItemsList = verDbHandler.getAllRememberItems();
    return rememberItemsList.size();
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    rememberItemsList = verDbHandler.getAllRememberItems();
    String _story = rememberItemsList.get(position).getStory();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return QuestionFragment.newInstance(0, _story);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

// Returns the page title for the top indicator
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return ("RecyclerTitle");
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

}

I am trying get the titles dynamically from the recyclerview, passing the required position / SN to load the corresponding story from the DB and then display in the "Question Fragment"

Comment: I have worked with viewpagers, but I have always been able to control the position and title of items loaded into the viewpager. Unlike here, where I feel I need to reload the list in the pagerAdapter, I really havent written any code on this, as I am trying to get the best logic to work it out.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes see Edit.

Comment: May be this could helps you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107433/view-pager-in-listview